# ERROR: column "name_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer You might need to specify "USING name_id::integer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

I've had the hardest time deploying my application to heroku.  When I've try running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate` I wind up getting an error stating

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "downtown_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING downtown_id::integer"
```

First thing I tried was this

```
  def change
      remove_column :properties, :downtown_id
      add_column :properties, :downtown_id, :integer
  end
```

No luck.

Then I tried this. (found from [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/18691-postgresql-vs-rails-migration-how-to-change-columns-from-string-to-integer)).

```
  def change
    change_column :properties, :downtown_id, 'integer USING CAST(downtown_id AS integer)'
  end
```

Still no luck. :(

Is there anything I need to do after I run these migrations on my dev environment first before i can try running them on a `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

I don't know what to do, and everything i've looked at points to the things i've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this syntax:

```rb
def change
  change_column :properties, :downtown_id, :integer, using: 'CAST(downtown_id AS integer)'
end
```